# Traced stolen crypto to exchange. Any way to get it back?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, currencies, cryptography, theft, ownership

A week my BTC was stolen (very likely some form of trojan/keylogger as I stupidly kept the keys on a computer which connects to the internet). After getting over the initial shock, I looked into the thieves activities.

Now there has been some movement on his/her address and I found a way to connect it to an exchange (Poloniex.com). Do you think it is reasonable to expect the exchange to get involved in this, if I reach out to them? Or will they just side with their customer and ignore me?

The paper trail:
My BTC was stolen on 6th of August and sent to this wallet: https://mempool.space/address/bc1qwhyawjvexu2uv0tll4cw2vvn05e8c9ak4pwv4z

He/she now split it between two addresses (a new one, and an older one with 92 transactions: https://mempool.space/address/3HmQHzjzT2t2s21pGoCyHyo2ZYXZbuifmP)

This older one has previously interacted with the Poloniex.com exchange: https://vivigle.com/BitWallet/wallet?address=12KQs513uwL6wNynQ3JP6efaocDjkE2w5C

I am very grateful for any input and information. Even if you say there is no way to get it back, I'm glad to learn more. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

> **Do you think it is reasonable to expect the exchange to get involved in this, if I reach out to them?**

I'd look at this from their point of view. A random stranger wants the exchange to give them money from one of their customers' accounts. Maybe the stranger says the money is stolen but the customer says it was payment for a painting. The exchange has no way to tell who is telling the truth. The exchange is bound by laws like GDPR to protect the personal details of their customer.

That means it might be necessary to get local police involved and pay a lawyer to communicate with the exchange.

At least a casual check suggests that it is hard for non-customers to communicate with exchanges at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis with poloniex is right and they are furthermore very likely a huobi.com client.

You need to get law enforcements help to contact the exchange in order to freeze available funds of the scammer or to get his id or bank data.